# How may I run a .py file in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, programming

In terminal, I run a python code like this way:

```
python code.py file.txt
```

Or it might also work as:

```
./code.py file.txt
```

Where the 'python' command is for running the job, 'code.py' is the python script and 'file.txt' is the file on which the code is working.

Now my query is, if I use the same code script in Jupyter notebook (i.e. not in the terminal, but from the laptop installed software), how should I execute the run in Jupyter notebook, as it requires the 'file.txt' file as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From jupyter-notebook, you can do:

!python script.py

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @danbaki. It helps. (just the .txt file also needs to be written at the end)

Comment: @Sak Naturally. All arguments you'd normally pass to the file, still go after the file name. All that changes is a `!` is put in front of `python`.

Comment: `%run script.py {args}` used to work too. I haven't tested that lately. You can even run a notebook from a notebook, with `%run ./secondarynotebook.ipynb`